# Struts to servlets or integrating struts and servlets

Tags: java, php, servlets, struts, amazon-web-services

I need to import contacts from hotmail,yahoo, gmail etc and I am plan to use http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/ which is a struts 1.2 based application  is that possible to integrate struts1.2  with servlets. After importing contacts I need to make use of Amazon Web services simple emailing service API to send bulk mails. Can we rewrite the struts based application to pure servlets based application. I have make use of Linkedin and facebook api's to update the information on linkedin and facebook, can I make use of the PHP api's with my servlets, does it will be a problem or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With socialauth only the example is using Struts, there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to use the same APIs with plain Servlets if that's the direction you want to take. I'd heavily recommend using some lightweight MVC framework even for a small application though.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that, Should I rewrite the structs (social auth) to servlets or can I use it directly with the servlets.

Comment: Surely you can use standalone servlets with any MVC but I'm not that sure it makes any sense. If you use an MVC like struts, why not use it for the entire app.. If you on the other hand believe you don't really need an MVC (which I doubt) then I'd rather recommend not taking on struts simply to use socialauth. AFAIK socialauth is not bound to struts, it only uses struts in the example.